# make the button link change depending on the slide I'm on

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm building my website/portfolio, so I made a slider of 3 images representing each of my 3 projects to present on my website. In the middle of the page I have a "Learn more" button, but I don't know how to make the button link change depending on the slide I'm on. How can I fix this?

```js
const slideContainer = document.querySelector(".slider")
const sliderText = document.querySelector(".slider--text")
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".slider__btn-left")
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".slider__btn-right")

const sliderImages = [{
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526726538690-5cbf956ae2fd?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1740&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "L'équipe de Nathan",
  },
  {
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517672651691-24622a91b550?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1932&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "Nathan's Darts",
  },
  {
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534093607318-f025413f49cb?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1740&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "E-commerce",
  },
]

let slideCounter = 0

const startSlider = () => {
  slideContainer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4),
      rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4)
    ), url(${sliderImages[0].src})`
  sliderText.innerHTML = sliderImages[0].text
}

btnRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (slideCounter === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    slideContainer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4),
      rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4)
    ), url(${sliderImages[0].src})`
    sliderText.innerHTML = sliderImages[0].text
    slideCounter = -1

    slideContainer.classList.add("fadeIn")
    setTimeout(() => {
      slideContainer.classList.remove("fadeIn")
    }, 1000)
  }
  slideContainer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4),
      rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4)
      ),url(${sliderImages[slideCounter + 1].src})`
  sliderText.innerHTML = sliderImages[slideCounter + 1].text
  slideCounter++
  slideContainer.classList.add("fadeIn")
  setTimeout(() => {
    slideContainer.classList.remove("fadeIn")
  }, 1000)
})

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (slideCounter === 0) {
    slideContainer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4),
      rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4)
    ),url(${sliderImages[sliderImages.length - 1].src})`
    sliderText.innerHTML = sliderImages[sliderImages.length - 1].text
    slideCounter = sliderImages.length
    slideContainer.classList.add("fadeIn")
    setTimeout(() => {
      slideContainer.classList.remove("fadeIn")
    }, 1000)
  }

  slideContainer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4),
      rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4)
    ),url(${sliderImages[slideCounter - 1].src})`
  sliderText.innerHTML = sliderImages[slideCounter - 1].text
  slideCounter--
  slideContainer.classList.add("fadeIn")
  setTimeout(() => {
    slideContainer.classList.remove("fadeIn")
  }, 1000)
})

startSlider()
```

```css
.slider {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider--content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider--feature {
  text-align: center;
}

.slider--title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.slider--text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.slider__btn-right,
.slider__btn-left {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.slider--btn {
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.8rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__btn-left:hover,
.slider__btn-right:hover {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider--content">
      <button class="slider__btn-left">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </button>
      <div class="slider--feature">
        <h1 class="slider--title">mes projets</h1>
        <p class="slider--text"></p>
        <a href="/projets/lequipe-de-nathan/lequipe-de-nathan.html" class="slider--btn">En savoir plus</a>
      </div>
      <button class="slider__btn-right">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the following changes:
In your HTML, for your learn more button, you could give an id and remove the href:

```
 <a id="learn_more_href" class="slider--btn">En savoir plus</a>
```

In your JavaScript File, you can target this element and set the href dynamically, for that:

1. Add a link in your object like this.

```js
const sliderImages = [
  {
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526726538690-5cbf956ae2fd?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1740&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "One",
    link: "https://www.google.com",
  },
  {
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517672651691-24622a91b550?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1932&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "Two",
    link: "https://www.instagram.com",
  },
  {
    src: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534093607318-f025413f49cb?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=1740&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    text: "E-commerce",
    link: "https://www.facebook.com",
  },
];
```

2. Find the learn more button:

```js
const learnMoreButton = document.getElementById("learn_more_href");
```

Add these lines at the end of your functions:

1. startScroll():

```js
learnMoreButton.setAttribute("href", sliderImages[0].link);
```

2. btnRight and btnLeft eventlisteners:

```js
learnMoreButton.setAttribute("href", sliderImages[slideCounter].link);
```

Hope you find this helpful.